# Gradle war errors

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I migrated from Maven to Gradle and exactly using the same dependencies. But when I deploy war file to the tomcat servers, I have been seeing errors

```
 "errMsg": "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.capitalize(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;",
"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation",
```

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url ''
        }
        maven {
            url ""
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.saliman:gradle-properties-plugin:1.4.6'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'war'
}
apply plugin: 'net.saliman.properties'
apply plugin: 'war'


group = ''
version = ''
description = ''
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url ""
    }
    maven {
        url ""
    }
}


sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
api 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
api 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'

api 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
api 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70'
api 'com.voltage.util.vibesimple:vibesimplejava:5.0.0'
api 'org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.2.9.RELEASE'
api ('org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.22.RELEASE'){
exclude group: 'commons-logging'
}
api 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.2.22.RELEASE'
api ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop-hbase:2.5.0.RELEASE'){
exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
exclude group: 'io.netty', module: 'netty'
exclude group: 'io.netty', module: 'netty-all'
exclude group: 'xerces', module: 'xercesImpl'
exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-hdfs'
exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager'
exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core'
exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-mapper-asl'
exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
exclude group: 'org.apache.avro', module: 'avro'
exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-common'
exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-compress'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-context'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-aop'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-expression'
exclude group: 'org.apache.zookeeper', module: 'zookeeper'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-beans'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-beans'
exclude group: 'javax.xml.bind', module: 'jaxb-api'
exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-core-asl'
exclude group: 'org.mortbay.jetty', module: 'jetty-util'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-messaging'
}
api 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.22.RELEASE'
api 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.22.RELEASE'
api 'org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.22.RELEASE'
api 'org.springframework:spring-test:5.2.22.RELEASE'
api 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
api ('io.searchbox:jest:6.3.1'){
exclude module: 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'
}
api 'io.searchbox:jest-common:6.3.1'
api ('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.3.1'){
exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
exclude group: 'org.yaml', module: 'snakeyaml'
exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', module: 'jackson-dataformat-cbor'
exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-api'
}
api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.6.6'
api 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.3.0'
api 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.16.1'
api ('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer:7.16.1'){
exclude group: 'om.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
}
api 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26'
api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.2'
api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2'
api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.14.2'
api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.0'
api 'org.json:json:20230227'
api 'net.sf.supercsv:super-csv:2.2.0'
api 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3'
api 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.16'
api 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.16'
api 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.16'
api 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.1'
api 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1'
api 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1'
api 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.17.1'
api ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:3.3.6') {
exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
}
api ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager:3.3.6') {
exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
}
api ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:3.3.6') {
exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'

}
api ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.6'){
exclude group: 'jdk.tools', module: 'jdk.tools'
exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-mapper-asl'
exclude group: 'commons-beanutils', module: 'commons-beanutils'
exclude group: 'xerces', module: 'xercesImpl'
exclude group: 'commons-beanutils', module: 'commons-beanutils-core'
exclude group: 'commons-lang', module: 'commons-lang'
exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
exclude group: 'org.apache.zookeeper', module: 'zookeeper'
exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-compress'
exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
exclude group: 'javax.xml.bind', module: 'jaxb-api'
exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-jaxrs'
exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-xc'
exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-core-asl'
exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpcore'
exclude group: 'org.yaml', module: 'snakeyaml'
exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
}
api ('org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:2.5.5'){
exclude group: 'jdk.tools', module: 'jdk.tools'
exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-mapper-asl'
exclude group: 'io.netty', module: 'netty-all'
exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core'
exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-common'
exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
exclude group: 'com.mapr.hadoop', module: 'maprfs'
exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'hadoop-auth'
exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
api 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:0.9.7'
api ('org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:2.5.5'){
exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
}
api 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
api 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.1.1'
api 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4'
api 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.31'
api 'org.springframework:spring-orm:5.2.22.RELEASE'
api 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.31.Final'
api ('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.5'){
exclude group: 'commons-io', module: 'commons-io'
}
api 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'
api 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.22'
api 'org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.4.31.Final'
api ('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.2'){
exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
}
api 'com.cyberark.sdk:javapasswordsdk:9.5.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.4.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.5.13'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.5.13'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.7'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.7'
}

// Copy the WAR file to the desired location
task copyWar(type: Copy) {
    from war.archiveFile
    into 'build/appBundle'
}

// Create a TAR.GZ archive containing the WAR file
task tarGz(type: Tar, dependsOn: copyWar) {
    from 'build/appBundle'
    archiveFileName = "${rootProject.name}-${version}.tar.gz"
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    archiveBaseName = rootProject.name
    destinationDirectory = file('build')
}
// Specify dependencies and ordering of tasks
copyWar.mustRunAfter 'war'
copyXlrInstall.mustRunAfter copyWar

// Define artifacts for publishing
artifacts {
    archives tarGz
}
```

I compared my maven target folder with build(libs) folder and all the dependencies are there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is version conflict but you are not showing any actual dependency in your question. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: @aled I checked all the dependencies its exactly same as maven

Comment: You are asking here but not giving readers the benefit of the needed information to troubleshoot the issue. The only possible answer with this level of information is that there seem to be a version mismatch *somewhere*.

Comment: @aled Sorry for the late response. Updates my code with all the dependencies above

Comment: Why are you using `plugins` and `apply plugin` in the same project, and even the same plugin? And why use the `java-library` and `war` plugins in the same project? That can cause issues I think.

Comment: Would [jHades](https://jhades.github.io/index.html) help debug your classpath/class loader issue?

Comment: run `gradlew dependencies` and check for presence of `org.apache.commons` and `org.apache.hadoop`

Comment: The dependency you have added is `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3`, but the class `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` is from `commons-lang:commons-lang`. You should either change the dependency or use the class `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` instead

Answer (score 0):

The method `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.capitalize()` belongs to `StringUtils` class residing in `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9` which is specified with `api` scope in your `build.gradle`. This means that the class is available at compile-time but not necessarily included into runtime dependencies.

In turn `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is a runtime error in Java which occurs when a method is called that exists at compile-time, but does not exist at runtime. So the problem is about the difference between your application's compile-time classpath and run-time classpath. To debug both please use built-in `dependencies` [task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html).

Most probably changing

```
api 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
```

to

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
```

will fix the issue. Anyway, you have to make sure that `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9` is available in the run-time classpath of your application, namely whether the corresponding jar file is included into resulting `*.war` file (inspect `/WEB-INF/lib` directory).

Comment: thanks for your answer. All the dependencies are there in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. I also ran `gradle dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath` and it showed me all the `hadoop` and `lang3` there as well.

Comment: Could you put the whole stack trace into your question? As far as I understand you run the app via Gradle. Do you face the same issue when running it as a stand-alone app?

Comment: So I have a limitation, I can't run my app locally. I can only deploy on Tomcat and then test it. But gradle build is always successful locally.

Comment: Ok, but can you put the more detailed stacktrace.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the corrected Gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url = "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.saliman:gradle-properties-plugin:1.4.6'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'war'
}
apply plugin: 'net.saliman.properties'
apply plugin: 'war'


group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'My first Gradle project'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"
    }
}


sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }`enter code here`
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // all my dependencies
    api 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.12'
    runtimeOnly fileTree(dir: 'web-inf/lib', include: '*jar')
}

// Copy the WAR file to the desired location
task copyWar(type: Copy) {
    from war.archiveFile
    into 'build/appBundle'
}

// Create a TAR.GZ archive containing the WAR file
task tarGz(type: Tar, dependsOn: copyWar) {
    from 'build/appBundle'
    archiveFileName = "${rootProject.name}-${version}.tar.gz"
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    archiveBaseName = rootProject.name
    destinationDirectory = file('build')
}
// Specify dependencies and ordering of tasks
copyWar.mustRunAfter 'war'
copyXlrInstall.mustRunAfter copyWar

// Define artifacts for publishing
artifacts {
    archives tarGz
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Same versions were working in maven.

Comment: I just checked and all the classes/JAR files are there in the classpath